# Symfony2 Form Dynamic Choice Field With EAV Returned Values

Tags: php, oop, symfony, symfony-forms

I am creating an E-Commerce Bundle with Symfony2 and Doctrine2. I am applying EAV approach for the product features and product values for unlimited features. For this, I have three basic entities: Product, FeatureKind and FeatureValues.

- FeatureKind is connected with FeatureValues with a OneToMany unidirectional
  relationship.
- Product is connected to FeatureKind with a ManyToMany relationship.

The Problem is the I need the FeatureType as labels and it's various values as a choice field in the product form. I have managed to get the featurekind and associated values in the product form but I don't know how to turn them into choice fields.

Following are all three Entities, Controller and Form Code and the result of my code.

**Note:** I have removed the extra things from code to keep it short.

Product.php

```
namespace Webmuch\ProductBundle\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="FeatureKind", inversedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_featurekind")
     **/
    private $featurekind;
}
```

FeatureKind.php

```
namespace Webmuch\ProductBundle\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="feature_kind")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class FeatureKind
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="FeatureValue")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="feature_kind_value",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="kind_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="value_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     **/
    protected $values;   
}
```

FeatureValue.php

```
namespace Webmuch\ProductBundle\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class FeatureValue
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $value;
}
```

ProductController.php

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Product();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $features = $em->getRepository('ProductBundle:FeatureKind')->findAll();

    foreach($features as $feature)
    {
        $featurekind = new FeatureKind();
        $featurekind->setTitle($feature->getTitle());
        foreach($feature->getValue() as $value ){
            $featurekind->getValue()->add($value);
        }
        $entity->getFeaturekind()->add($featurekind);   
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $entity);

     if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('product_show', array(
                'id' => $entity->getId()
            )));
        }
    }
    return $this->render('ProductBundle:Product:new.html.twig', array(
       'form'   => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

ProductType.php

```
namespace Webmuch\ProductBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('featurekind', 'collection', array('type' => new FeatureKindType()))
            ->getForm();
        }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Webmuch\ProductBundle\Entity\Product',
            'required' => true
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'product';
    }
}
```

FeatureKindType.php

```
namespace Webmuch\ProductBundle\Form;

class FeatureKindType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('value','collection', array(
                                               'type' => new FeatureValueType(),
                                               'allow_add'=>true))
            ->getForm();
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Webmuch\ProductBundle\Entity\FeatureKind',
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'featurekind';
    }
}
```

[image: This is my form result.]

**EDIT:**

I after a few days of work, I am now stuck with a simple array of features and their respective multiple values:

```
Array
(
    [Color] => Array
        (
            [Red] => Red
            [Green] => Green
        )

    [Size] => Array
        (
            [Large] => Large
            [Medium] => Medium
            [Small] => Small
        )

    [Sleeve Style] => Array
        (
            [Half Sleeved] => Half Sleeved
            [Full Sleeved] => Full Sleeved
            [Cut Sleeves] => Cut Sleeves
        )

)
```

I have tried to create the form as follows: **$this->choices** contains the array.

```
$builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('slug')
    ->add('active')
;

foreach ($this->choices as $choice) {
    $builder->add('featurekind', 'choice', array(
        'required' => 'false',
        'choices' => $choice,
        'empty_value' => 'Choose an option',
        'empty_data'  => null
    ));
}

$builder->getForm();
```

The above doesn't work on the property **$featurekind**. I get the error:

```
Notice: Object of class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection could not be converted to int in /vagrant/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ChoiceList.php line 457
```

Although if the form field is attached to any un-associated property, for example: $name, it  still creates only one form field for the last iteration of the loop.

I am out of options.

Comment: You did not show your FeatureKindType

Comment: And now you did not show FeatureValueType. What do you want to get? A label with the FeatureKind name and then a drop down with all the possible feature values?

Comment: @carlos-granados That's exactly what I want. FeatureValueType has nothing but a simple text field for property `$builder->add('value')`. That's why I didn't post it.

Comment: I have to leave now. I´ll come back in a few hours. If you have not found a solution by then I´ll give it a try

Comment: I have been thinking of this while I was away and what you want to do cannot be done with your current class structure. I´ll explain in an answer

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how to change the class structure and still maintain my EAV approach. I'll wait for your answer. I have tried a lot of things with this. I'm really unable to change those values into a choice field.

Comment: you can get from your view the variables to show the label  forms.vars something like this

Comment: No I haven't figured out a solution yet. Now I'm trying to do something like SyliusAssortmentBundle. I'm trying to see what they've done, but the structure is very hard to understand with models, entities and interfaces for everything. Let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: The Link [How To Embed EAV Model In Symfony2 Collection Form](http://webmuch.com/embed-eav-model-symfony2-collection-form/) helped us to resolved this type of requirement .

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do cannot be done with your current structure. Let me try to explain: FeatureKind has a one to many relationship with FeatureValue. This means that you can have a "color" kind which can have values "red","pink" etc.. This is fine. But your product entity has a collection of FeatureKind objects, so it can have a list like "Color", "Size", etc... BUT (this is the most important part) it has no way of asiginig a specific Value to any of these Kinds: there is no property which holds the specific value for each kind. I hope you could undestand this, it is a bit difficult to explain.

What you need to do:

Define your FeatureValue and FeatureKind classes just as they are.

Define a NEW entity which handles an association between a kind and a value for a product:

```
namespace Webmuch\ProductBundle\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class FeatureKindValue
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="features")
     **/
    private $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FeatureKind")
     **/
    protected $kind;   

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FeatureValue")
     **/
    protected $value;   
}
```

This entity handles pairs of kind:value, for example color:red

Finally, your product entity has a property of this new type:

```
namespace Webmuch\ProductBundle\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FeatureKindValue", mappedBy="product")
     **/
    private $features;
}
```

Then, in order to present the form as you want, do something similar to the instructions given in the answer to this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316461/symfony2-how-to-create-form-based-on-dynamic-parameters-from-db-eav)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have gone over and tried your method but it doesn't work. If you see the image, I have all the correct values at the fore front within my form already connected to the right kinds. All I needed is to make the kinds into label for a choice field with all the values. This will make a product that will have Size:Large and Color:Green for example.

Comment: I will then create multiple of these products and connect them to a MasterProduct and again make a choice field from all the values from the multiple connected product entities. This question only asks about the single sub-product form that already has all the values in the form but as text fields, I want them as choice fields.

Comment: I could be way off about the answer and not getting whole concept as such. Do let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: Not sure how to get what you want but I am sure that with your original structure it cannot be done

Answer (score 1):

This kind of stuff can be tricky, but you can use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723713/access-entity-data-inside-formtype-for-a-child-in-a-collection-in-symfony2) in your `FeatureKindType` class:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (DataEvent $event) use ($builder) {
            /* @var FormBuilderInterface $builder */
            $form = $event->getForm();
            /* @var FeatureKind $data */
            $data = $event->getData();
            if ($data !== null) {
                $form->add(
                    $builder->getFormFactory()->createNamed(
                        'values',
                        'entity',
                        null,
                        array(
                            'label' => $data->getName(),
                            'class' => 'WebmuchProductBundle:FeatureValue',
                        )
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Mind you, I have not tried to post the form and save the entities in your case, but the form now diplays the name of the `FeatureKind` as label and a dropdown select containing the respective `FeatureKindValues`.

I use this approach in a project of mine, and it works for me.